# where can one find code base for power BI visuals, like for radial gauge chart

Tags: powerbi

Where can one find code base for power BI visuals, I need code for radial gauge chart to customize it.

I have tried searching google and posting it in power BI community but have not found an answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Microsoft uses GitHub for its Power BI visuals' repositories. I understand the radial gauge is one of the earlier ones and was developed using Microsoft's earlier approach, so its coding structure doesn't align with the current documentation and approach for how to develop visuals. (You'll likely experience some issues just trying to tweak it.)

Anyhow, I believe [this is the TypeScript for it.](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-core/blob/master/src/Clients/Visuals/visuals/gauge.ts) It is located within https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-core, which has been deprecated. Check out https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals for information about how to code custom visuals for Power BI the current way.